# onDestroy() is getting called after onPause()

Tags: android, canvas, colors, paint, ondestroy

I am implementing paint Application. My problem is that when i color on object.After some times screen goes to sleep.When i awake the screen, my old paint lost. I find out issue its calling OnDestroy after Onpause automatically so it clears canvas. How to stop calling Ondestroy automatically.

Comment: onDestroy is called only when the system is shutting down your app. I think you mean onStop() is being called? Check out the activity life cycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't try to circumvent Android's activity workflow and memory management by avoiding `onDestroy()` (in fact, I think you can't).

Use [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to store your current state and restore it on [`onCreate(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), if a Bundle is provided.

Comment: i have solved issue. It was calling onStop due to memory management problem and after that onDestroy. I solved it by memory managment